# Check is a node exist and check it's attribute value

Tags: php, xpath, attributes, nodes, simplexml

I have a xml file with nodes and attributes

```
<hotspot name="hs1"/>
<hotspot name="hs2"/>
<hotspot name="hs3"/>
```

I would like to check if the nodc hotspot exist and if a specific attribute value exist.
I'm trying this but id doesn't work...

```
<?php
$file = 'hotspots.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$var = $xml->xpath("//hotspot[@name='hs2']");
if (isset($var)) { echo 'does exist' } else {echo 'does not exist'}
?>
```

Well, it doesn't work at all (error 500)
Sorry for being such a newbee, help much appreciated ! THX !

Comment: That's not an XML file. See also the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289

Comment: Well it's a part of my xml file ;)

Comment: @jeromebg Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statements should end with a `;`

```
$file = 'hotspots.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$var = $xml->xpath("//hotspot[@name='hs2']");
if (isset($var)) {
    echo 'does exist';
} else {
    echo 'does not exist';
}
```

Besides that, the return type of `$xml->xpath` is an array and when the xpath expression finds no results it will return an empty array.

When it returns an empty array, `isset($var)` will be true and will give you `does exist` which is not correct.

One option could be to use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to check if the array contains more than 0 items:

`if (count($var) > 0) {`